# Presenting a View Controller when the Interface Orientation is Upside Down

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, presentviewcontroller

My iPhone app supports the upside down interface orientation:
When the user turns the phone upside down (so that the home button is on top) the whole user interface is flipped vertically.

However, a problem occurs when trying to present some view controller **B** from my view controller **A** (in this example I present the standard mail composer view controller):

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailVC = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
    mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

When this method is triggered the first thing that happens is that (blue) view controller **A** immediately flips vertically without animation for whatever reason (as seen in the first screenshot) → Why?

Next the presented view controller **B** moves into the view (as it should) from the bottom.

[image: presenting view controller B]

When dismissing view controller **B** it flips at an instant and the moves out of the view to the top (instead of the direction where it came from, as seen in the second screenshot).

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

[image: dismissing view controller B]

**Is this a bug in iOS or how can I avoid this odd behavior?**

(I only want the same standard animation for presenting view controllers as in normal portrait mode - without these flips.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that `MFMailComposeViewController` doesn't support upside down interface orientation that's why it could be interpreted as bug. **But** Apple recommends do not use upside down interface orientation for iPhone apps. The main reason of it could be explained by such example:

1. User opens application and rotate iPhone to upside down orientation.
2. At this moment somebody calls him by phone.
3. User tries to answer the calls and forgets to rotate phone to default portrait orientation.
4. As result iPhone's microphone is near user's ear and speaker near mouth.

It isn't user-friendly experience.
I would have thought on your site to use upside down orientation or not.

However if using of upside down interface orientation is required condition then you make such trick:
Create category to `MFMailComposeViewController` and override method `supportedInterfaceOrientations` to allow support of necessary orientations and import it to class were `MFMailComposeViewController` is created:

```
// MFMailComposeViewController+Orientation.h file
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface MFMailComposeViewController (Orientation)

@end

// MFMailComposeViewController+Orientation.m file
#import "MFMailComposeViewController+Orientation.h"

@implementation MFMailComposeViewController (Orientation)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

@end
```

**Notice:** I am not sure that this trick would be passed throw Apple application approving center cause of overriding existed methods in category.

Comment: Those are good points against using the upside down orientation. But my app is supposed to be used in conjunction with a microphone that can only be attached to the bottom of the iPhone. So in order to use the app for its purpose the use *has to* rotate the iPhone.

Comment: @Mischa I have updated my answer with code that makes MFMailComposeViewController to open correctly if application in upside down orientation.

Comment: Funny, I tried the same thing with subclassing `MFMailComposeViewController` instead of creating a category for it and for some reason that did *not* work. Your solution works great. Thanks a lot!